# Beautiful Soup find a class next to a TD

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table, tags

Here the code

```
<tr class="even">
<td>**keyword** </td>
<td class="separator"></td>
<td>
<span title="blablabla" class="data-siloing">**Text I want**</span> </td>
</tr>
```

How can I get this text using beautifulsoup ?

Try to get the text between span tag with class after a TD knowed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '''\
<tr class="even">
<td>**keyword** </td>
<td class="separator"></td>
<td>
<span title="blablabla" class="data-siloing">**Text I want**</span> </td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

# 1. find the td with "keyword"
keyword_td = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td' and 'keyword' in tag.text)

# 2. find the next span tag
span = keyword_td.find_next('span')

# 3. get the text
print(span.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
**Text I want**
```